# Can I use Qt.createComponent() in WorkerScript?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I'm new in Qt quick app. (QML)

I wanna create dynamic image table(like in Samegame example) but it using thread to make real-time create by using workerScript.

How to using WorkerScript by Qt function can be passed between the new thread and the parent thread? or can import Qt func in javascript?

example

//main.qml
    import QtQuick 1.0

```
Rectangle {
    width: 800; height: 600

    WorkerScript {
        id: myWorker
        source: "script.js"
    }

    Item {
        id: container
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Component.onCompleted: myWorker.sendMessage({ 'container':container })
}
```

//script.js

```
WorkerScript.onMessage = function(message) {

    // error occur in this below line with TypeError: Result of expression 'Qt.createComponent' [undefined] is not a function.

    var component = Qt.createComponent("Imgbox.qml");  

    if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
        var img = component.createObject(message.container);
    }
}
```

//Imgbox.qml

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Image {
    id: img
    source: "./img.jpg"; clip: true
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Components cannot be created in a thread.  If it is just the cost of loading the image that is the problem, you can load them in the background by setting asynchronous: true